# how to override default xml generation from Jersey REST webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jaxb, jersey

I am totally new to Jersey REST webservice, I just get some simple XML generated by using
@GET
@Produces
@Path in the resource file, I know there is a way to override default JAXB format of genereated XML but the question is how? Is there any basic tutorial to show how to do that? I am currently using Jersey so I would like to know how to integrat JAXB and Jersey together, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A JAXB (JSR-222) implementation is automatically integrated with a JAX-RS implementation such as Jersey for converting POJOs corresponding to parameters & return types to/from XML.  JAXB doesn't require any annotations but you can explore the ones in the `javax.xml.bind.annotation` package to see what's available to customize the XML representation.